# Purpose of "computer" section in MySQL Cluster 7.2?

Tags: mysql-cluster, mysql5.5

According to the cluster documentation, you can either define data nodes with:

```
[ndbd]
NodeId=n
HostName=1.2.3.4
```

or

```
[ndbd]
NodeId=n
ExecuteOnComputer=m

[computer]
Id=m
HostName=1.2.3.4
```

I don't see a substantial difference between the two. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-computer-definition.html) has this to say:

> The [computer] section has no real significance other than serving as
>   a way to avoid the need of defining host names for each node in the
>   system.

I'm stumped. If I have to define a hostname, what benefit is there to defining it in [computer] instead of [ndbd]?

Answer (score 1):

Its more a matter of convenience and clarity I would say. For example if you are referring the same `HostName` in multiple places in the config file, its better to define it under `[computer]` section and use the corresponding `Id` in `[ndbd]` sections. Also, if in case you have to change the `HostName` in the future, you would just have to change it under the `[computer]` section.